# Fill ipywidget dropdown with content of CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dropdown

If I want to create a dropdown with ipywidget, I can do something like :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

test = widgets.Dropdown(options=['hello', 'world'], value=None)
test
```

This code allow to put two choices in the dropdown : hello and world.

Now, I've these data :

```
Date,Value
2020-01-28,103424
2020-01-28,103424
2020-01-28,103424
2020-01-28,103424
2020-01-28,103424
2020-01-28,103424
2020-01-28,103424
2020-01-28,103424
```

I try to create two dropdowns : one with the content of the Date column and the other with the content of the Value columns :

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/xxx/xxx/xxx/data.csv", usecols =["Date"])
df2 = pd.read_csv("/xxx/xxx/xxx/data.csv", usecols =["Value"])

d = widgets.Dropdown(options=[df])
d

d2 = widgets.Dropdown(options=[df2])
d2
```

But it doesn't work...

Do you have any ideas to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the column/Series you need in the dropdown from your input dataframe.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("/xxx/xxx/xxx/data.csv", usecols =["Date", "Value"])

d = widgets.Dropdown(options=df['Date'])
d2 = widgets.Dropdown(options=df['Value'])
display(d)
display(d2)
```